# Display an overlay to fit parent when it is a grid area

Tags: html, css

I have a grid (`containers`) to display a `navbar`, a `main-container` and a `footer`. In the `main-container`, it is also a grid to display 3 children elements in a custom disposition using `grid-area`. Everything works properly.

Now, I would like to display an overlay div (`overlay`) which has to fit the whole `main-container`. To do so, I just add an additional div in the `main-container` with the property `height: 100%; width: 100%;` and play with the `position` property without success. Indeed, `position: absolute` or `position: fixed` make it too big and I don't want to set a fixed width or height since the layout can be responsive. And with `position: relative`, it is not working neither.

Do you have any idea, how I could make the overlay display above the `main-container` while keeping the properties `width: 100%; height: 100%;`?

```css
#containers {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "navbar main" "navbar footer";
  grid-template-rows: calc(100% - 32px) 32px;
  grid-template-columns: 56px calc(100% - 56px);
}

#navbar-container {
  grid-area: navbar;
  background-color: blue;
}

#main-container {
  grid-area: main;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'child1 child2' 
    'child1 child3';
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

#footer-container {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: black;
}

#child1,
#child2,
#child3 {
  padding: 10px;
}

#child1 {
  grid-area: child1;
  background-color: red;
}

#child2 {
  grid-area: child2;
  background-color: purple;
}

#child3 {
  grid-area: child3;
  background-color: pink;
}

#footer-container {
  grid-area: footer;
}

.modal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="containers">
  <div id="navbar-container"></div>
  <div id="main-container">
    <div id="child1">
      <span>CHILD 1</span>
    </div>
    <div id="child2">
      <span>CHILD 2</span>
    </div>
    <div id="child3">
      <span>CHILD 3</span>
    </div>
    <div class="modal">
      MODAL
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer-container"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to make the parent `relative` and the modal `absolute`.

```css
#containers {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "navbar main" "navbar footer";
  grid-template-rows: calc(100% - 32px) 32px;
  grid-template-columns: 56px calc(100% - 56px);
}

#navbar-container {
  grid-area: navbar;
  background-color: blue;
}

#main-container {
  grid-area: main;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'child1 child2' 
    'child1 child3';
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  position: relative;
}

#footer-container {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: black;
}

#child1,
#child2,
#child3 {
  padding: 10px;
}

#child1 {
  grid-area: child1;
  background-color: red;
}

#child2 {
  grid-area: child2;
  background-color: purple;
}

#child3 {
  grid-area: child3;
  background-color: pink;
}

#footer-container {
  grid-area: footer;
}

.modal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="containers">
  <div id="navbar-container"></div>
  <div id="main-container">
    <div id="child1">
      <span>CHILD 1</span>
    </div>
    <div id="child2">
      <span>CHILD 2</span>
    </div>
    <div id="child3">
      <span>CHILD 3</span>
    </div>
    <div class="modal">
      MODAL
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer-container"></div>
</div>
```